# Customize Full-Screen Behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-fullscreen

Per the android docs, we can make an activity go full-screen by adding the following block of code in the `onCreate` method (inside `setContent{...}`, specifically, if you are using Compose)

```
val windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView)
windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
```

However, this seems to only hide the information displayed on the statusbar, replacing it with just a black stripe.

Now, my question is - How can we modify the color of this stripe so that the UI of the app seems to extend to the entire display?

I am not sure where to start but I've heard accompanist MAY have something related to this, but I thought it better to post this question here, so that if anyone already knows a way around, they may share since it will be helpful to the community.

Other than that, solutions that do not involve accompanist are also welcome, and may be even preferred.

For reference, here's the output as of now

[image: Preview]

Notice the black bar at the top? That's the target.

Answer (score 1):

copy and paste it in onCreate  method after result you can understand

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val window: Window = window
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        val decorView: View = window.getDecorView()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        } else {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        }
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }
```